# Magento Class "string" does not exists - Put email Transport Object into RabbitMQ queue

Tags: magento2.4.1

Magento 2.4.4-p1 EE

PHP 8.1.7

**I want to put email Transport Object into RabbitMQ queue.**

communication.xml

```
<topic name="my_topic" request="Magento\Email\Model\Transport\Interceptor"/>
```

queue_publisher.xml

```
<publisher topic="my_topic">
    <connection name="amqp" exchange="my_exchange"/>
</publisher>
```

queue_topology.xml

```
<exchange name="my_exchange" type="topic" connection="amqp">
    <binding id="MyTest"
             topic="my_topic"
             destinationType="queue"
             destination="my_destination"/>
</exchange>
```

queue_consumer.xml

```
<consumer name="my_test.consumer"
          queue="my_destination"
          connection="amqp"
          handler="handler::process"/>
```

**Test with Magento CLI**

app/code/Vendor/Module/Command/TestQueue.php

```
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherInterface;
...
...
...
$this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
    $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        self::XML_PATH_TEST_TEMPLATE,
        ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    )
)->setTemplateOptions(
    [
        'area'  => FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
        'store' => Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
    ]
)->setTemplateVars(
    [
        'number'   => $number
    ]
)->setFromByScope(
    $sender
)->addTo(
    $recipient
);
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport(); 
try {
    $this->publisher->publish('my_topic', $transport);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->logger->critical($e);
    $output->writeln(sprintf('<error>%s</error>', $e->getMessage()));
}
$transport->sendMessage();
```

**After execution, an error message and Queue has no data**

**Class "string" does not exist**

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the IDE that you're using is added this at the top of the class

```
use string;
```